# Wi-Fi not detected

Tags: wireless

I have just loaded Ubuntu 15.10. I am already well pleased compared to Windows 10, BUT I cannot get the Wi-Fi detected. The Internet works via an Ethernet cable. Could one of you kind people explain to me how to get it up and running?

Comment: What is your wifi adapter ??? We can't help without this information, you likely need a driver, please edit your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

try doing the following on the Terminal:

```
sudo stop network-manager
sudo start network-manager
```

Many times restarting the network-manager helps in order to fix WiFi issues. Also you need to specify which Hardware are you using.

try using `lspci` and find the **network controller**

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 15.10 normally has no problem identifying your WiFi hardware.
Click on the network status icon displayed in  uppermost, right-hand corner group. Check that WiFi is enabled (a 'tick' should be displayed. If not then try clicking on it)

Comment: "Ubuntu 15.10 normally has no problem identifying your WiFi hardware" Thats just not true, there are many adapters not covered by the kernel driver, support gets better every day but it will never cover every possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting manually.
I had the same problem of not detecting the Wifi, but could connect it manually.

- Go to `Connect to Hidden Networks`.
- Select `new`
- Enter the `SSID` and `password` details.

Click `connect`.